# Expected identifier or '(' in simple for-loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors, cs50, expected-exception

I write functiton, that check is string contain only letters or not. If i declare `n` outside the loop:

```
int n = strlen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

it has no errors and works great, but if i move `n` declaration inside:

```
for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
```

i have errors:

```
vigenere.c:71:21: error: expected identifier or '('
    for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
                    ^
vigenere.c:71:21: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
vigenere.c:71:21: error: expected expression
vigenere.c:71:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
    for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
                                             ^
vigenere.c:71:47: error: expected ')'
    for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
                                              ^
vigenere.c:71:9: note: to match this '('
    for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
        ^
vigenere.c:71:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
                                                ^
6 errors generated.
```

Why? I have the same loop in main() and it's work great.
Can somebody explain me the problem?
Thanks!

Fuction entirely:

```
int is_alpha_string(string str)
{
    //for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
    int n = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(str[i]) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Don't compare functions with a boolean result with `1` or `0`! `if ( !isalpha(..) )` is much easier to read (`!` reads as "not"), just speak out loud both expressions.

Comment: Did you try removing the second `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int i = 0, int n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
```

(Note that the syntax here is much the same as it would be for any declaration of multiple variables with the same type, regardless of whether it's in a for loop or not.)

Comment: Thanks! I knew that i made something stupid. I'm newbie in C and I tired. Need to sleep :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the second int

```
for (int i = 0, **int** n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
```

instead use

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(str); i < n; i++)
```

Comment: "You don't need" - it actually is illegal, not just optional.